# Mediawiki RSS Extension not showing images

Tags: php, rss, mediawiki, feed, mediawiki-extensions

I have installed Extension:RSS and followed the instructions given to display images from feeds.

The same problem is being discussed on the Extension:RSS Talk page [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Scs77xou1rjfq8di). I installed the Extension:RSS as instructed [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RSS)

I added to `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgRSSAllowLinkTag = true;
$wgRSSAllowImageTag = true;
$wgAllowExternalImages = true;
```

I commented out the lines of code in `RSSparser.php` as specified here:

> If you allow to see images in feed items. Do not confuse this parameter with `$wgAllowImageTag` of MediaWiki core, Display of images causes privacy problems, because the image is fetched in the browser context, so the (image-) server log will contain data of the requesting browser, see the discussion here. Note that since 2013 due to the MediaWiki sanitizer, image tags which have the form `<img src="blah"/>` are not parsed correctly by the MediaWiki core sanitizer and are not displayed irrespective of this setting (see task T48443).

> If you want the image to show, set this to true in `LocalSettings.php` and in `\extensions\RSS\RSSParser.php` remove this part at lines 485
>
> ```
> if ( isset( $wgRSSAllowImageTag ) && $wgRSSAllowImageTag ) {
>    $extraInclude[] = "img";
> } else {
>     $extraExclude[] = "img";
> }
> ```

I validated the RSS file [here](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator) with the [RSS feed I want to import](https://archaix.wiki/data/RSS_Test.rss).

The MediaWiki page where I am testing the RSS import is [here](https://archaix.wiki/index.php/RSS_Test).

I believe it is MediaWiki's Santizer that is still stripping out the images, but I thought the instructions above addressed that issue.

Still, images do not show on the [page](https://archaix.wiki/index.php/RSS_Test).

Would anyone have a suggestion as to what else I should try?